# Laravel Lighthouse pass data from parent to child

Tags: laravel-lighthouse

Having a nested field will call a few methods with this signature:

```php
        $_,
        array $args,
        GraphQLContext $context,
        ResolveInfo $resolveInfo
```

`$_` would be the parent data but you can't send anything from parent to the child, using that obviously so you have to use `$resolveInfo` somehow I guess.

Here's an example let's say we have a parent at `properties` and a child at `properties.data`

Here are the two functions

```php
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Queries;

use GraphQL\Type\Definition\ResolveInfo;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Contracts\GraphQLContext;

final class PropertiesFiltered
{
    /**
     * @param null $_
     * @param array{} $args
     */
    public function parent(
        $_,
        array $args,
        GraphQLContext $context,
        ResolveInfo $resolveInfo
    ) {
        // Attempt 1   
        $resolveInfo->lookAhead()->queryPlan()["data"]["args"]["ok"] = true;
        // Attempt 2
        $resolveInfo->argumentSet->addValue("properties.data.ok", true);

        return [
            "facets" => [
                "rooms" => [
                    "step" => "1",
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param null $_
     * @param array{} $args
     */
    public function child(
        $_,
        array $args,
        GraphQLContext $context,
        ResolveInfo $resolveInfo
    ) {
        dd($resolveInfo->argumentSet->toArray());
    }
}
```

None of my attempts worked in the child I always get:

```bash
array:2 [
  "first" => 0
  "page" => 10
]
```

which means `ok` doesn't get added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$_, the first argument is the actual parent,

So for the parent resolver, let's say you have:

```php
    public function parent(
        $_,
        array $args,
        GraphQLContext $context,
        ResolveInfo $resolveInfo
    ) {
        return [
            "ok" => true,
            "facets" => [
                "rooms" => [
                    "step" => "1",
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Don't worry, in the final json response, the `ok` property will be cleaned up by lighthouse.

However, before that, it is passed "as-id" to the child resolvers as the parent argument. So you can get back your value in you child resolver as following:

```php
    /**
     * @param null $_
     * @param array{} $args
     */
    public function child(
        $parent,
        array $args,
        GraphQLContext $context,
        ResolveInfo $resolveInfo
    ) {
        dd($parent['ok']); // true
    }
```

Of course, this only works as direct parent->child relation

Comment: That sound like a fun idea, since ok is not a part of the request then it won't be used by lighthouse I guess right?

Comment: Yes, when crafting the API response, Lighthouse will get all requested fields from each node. Fields not present in request wont be used. And also, fields not in your schema can't be requested by end-user.